# Overriding WndProc to discard certain messages

Tags: c++, windows, wndproc

Say if you'd make a forms application and override the WndProc function to discard or change any message that's either WM_CLOSE, WM_DESTROY or WM_QUIT , would this make the application not closeable? how does Windows handle this?

Comment: It's still closable. Watch me click and have Task Manager call `TerminateProcess` on it.

Comment: You can do the same without overriding WndProc, just using FormClosing event. But application can be killed by Task Manager.